How to make bootstrap list groups highlight color uniform
I'm working on a website that uses Bootstrap's horizontal list groups. Everything works great, but when I hover over a particular list group, the highlighting effect is not also changing the background color of the text elements, which creates odd looking white boxes. How can I make the background color of those elements also change to the highlight color so the entire list group appears uniform?


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3 border-0" aria-current="true">
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
  </a>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3 border-0" aria-current="true">
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
  </a>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3 border-0" aria-current="true">
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Some text</li>
  </a>
</ul>



I've tried various different css styles, but I'm not good at css so I'm sure I'm not doing it correctly.

Your HTML is invalid. An anchor is not an allowed child of a list element. Be sure you're using a good editor or an HTML validator. Ask yourself whether it makes sense to wrap a stack of list items with an anchor. (Using a hash symbol as your ref URL is a good indicator that you're misusing the element.)

You're also nesting list items (by class), which probably messes with Bootstrap's intended styling.

Please tag Bootstrap by version. It's a critical part of your question.

This code is taken directly from bootstraps documentation. I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Bootstrap would not provide invalid HTML. If I'm wrong, show a link. Here's mine. You seem to have combined various list formats into one Frankensteinian monstrosity. I suggest starting fresh.

Horizontal list groups. Here's mine Same page you were looking at and has nested list items (by class). And bootstrap uses a hash symbol in their examples just to have the link do nothing. Bootstrap version is right in the code I posted.

Nowhere is there an anchor element as a child of a list element. You're mistaken. We can't move on until you understand that.

Your original complaint was that I was nesting list items (by class). The bootstrap example clearly does that. There are other bootstrap examples that wrap a bunch of elements in an anchor link, and the code clearly works. If you know of a way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish better, please post that.

Here is the correct code for anyone that finds this looking for the answer.
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3" aria-current="true">
  <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3" aria-current="true">
  <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

